# Cannot invoke 'moveDistance' with an argument list of type '(distance: (CGVector, fadeInWithDuration: Double))'

Tags: swift, swift3

Running an SKAction method but having some problems with the syntax. I started from the beginning and filled everything in the way that Xcode 8 code completion was telling me to but still no luck.

> Cannot invoke 'moveDistance' with an argument list of type '(distance: (CGVector, fadeInWithDuration: Double))'

a.swift

```
extension SKAction {
class func moveDistance(distance:CGVector, fadeInWithDuration duration:TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: duration)
    let moveIn = SKAction.move(by: distance, duration: duration)
    return SKAction.group([fadeIn, moveIn])
}
}
```

b.swift

```
// legacy
// //gameOverLayer?.runAction(SKAction.moveDistance(CGVectorMake(0, 100), fadeInWithDuration: 0.2)))

// Swift 3
gameOverLayer?.run(SKAction.moveDistance(distance: (CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100), fadeInWithDuration: 0.2)))
```

After hrs I realized I added 1 too many parenthesis ...yes noob.

Comment: `SKAction.moveDistance(distance: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100), fadeInWithDuration: 0.2)`

Comment: simple mistake just delete the question. I would change the declaration to `extension SKAction {
    class func move(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat, fadeIn duration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
        return SKAction.group([ SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: duration),
                                SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy), duration: duration) ])
    }
}`

Comment: and to call `.run(SKAction.move(dx: 0, dy: 100, fadeIn: 0.2))`

Comment: Thanks Leo. Will delete.

Comment: Actually Leo since there is a full answer with refactored extension and added function call could you please add an answer and I'll mark it as correct.  Thank you.

Comment: already posted the comment as an answer. You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your extension method to make it easier for you when calling it as follow:

```
extension SKAction {
    class func move(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat, fadeIn duration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
        return SKAction.group([ SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: duration),
                                SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy), duration: duration) ])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SKAction.move(dx: 0, dy: 100, fadeIn: 0.2)
```